# Rails break method keeps looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In `Trial` model, I have a method that creates a unique number by concatenating the last two digits of the year with a sequential number starting from 00.

```
before_create :create_trial_number

def count_records_from_same_year
  self.class.where(season_year: (season_year.beginning_of_year..season_year.end_of_year)).count
end

def create_trial_number
  loop do
    year = (season_year).strftime("%y")
    self.trial_number = year.concat(sprintf '%02d', count_records_from_same_year)
    break unless self.class.where(trial_number: self.trial_number).exists?
  end
end
```

If I create two trials numbering `"1800"`, `"1801"`, and then delete `"1800"`, and try to create a new trial, I would like it to recreate `"1800"` again.

But it seems to ignore this. The `create_trial_number` method doesn't break, and keeps looping. I get this error:

```
CACHE Trial Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "trials" WHERE "trials"."trial_number" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["trial_number", 1801], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

There might be a more streamlined way of doing this.

Comment: It might be tangential to the issue you're having, but it isn't really clear to me why this has a `loop` and `break`. It doesn't look like anything changes when the loop restarts so you'll always get an infinite loop if it doesn't break the first time.

Comment: Right, I understand. Well the break is meant to exit the loop if the number is already created, but I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started with 2 records 1800 and 1801.

You then deleted 1800, so `count_records_from_same_year` will return 1. You will now get an infinite loop since `year.concat(sprintf '%02d', count_records_from_same_year)` will evaluate to 1801 which already exists.

If you want to handle the recreation of deleted trial numbers, try the following.

```
def create_trial_number
  current_count = count_records_from_same_year
  year = (season_year).strftime("%y")

  if current_count.zero?
    self.trial_number = year.concat(sprintf '%02d', current_count)
  else
    expected_trial_numbers = (0..current_count).map{|i| "#{year}#{sprintf '%02d', i}".to_i }
    existing_trial_numbers = self.class.where(season_year: (season_year.beginning_of_year..season_year.end_of_year)).order(:trial_number).pluck(:trial_number)

    self.trial_number = (expected_trial_numbers - existing_trial_numbers).first
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks AbM. This is giving me numbers of 1800, 180001, 18000102 when trials are created.

Comment: @DollarChills added a fix by `dup`licating the year string since `concat` mutates the original string

Comment: Now the last two digits don't seem to be incrementing. Just created three records of 1800.

Comment: Is the trial_number a string or an integer in the database?

Comment: It is an integer.

Comment: Made an edit by calling `to_i` on the concatenated string

Comment: Brilliant! Of the testing i've done it seems to work as it should. Appreciate the help on this, been stumping me for a while now.